# What is the name for this phenomenon, and what are some other examples of it?

Tags: terminology, reference-request, cognates, perfect

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't figure out how to search for this, especially since my only example involves two function words.

In English, we can say "I have not eaten." "Have" here is being used in a different sense than "to have."

The interesting thing is that in Chinese you can also say "我没有吃饭” (I have not eaten) but also it happens that 没有 can mean to "not have" in the sense of not possessing something.

So both have and 有 share these two distinct senses in the two different languages. I know I've noticed other examples of this multi-sense matching before, but I think of any right now. Is there some term I can search for to find more examples? I'm especially interested in cases where one of the senses is more of a grammatical/function word than a content word.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relationship between possession ("to have") and tenses ("I have seen")](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/7184/relationship-between-possession-to-have-and-tenses-i-have-seen)

Comment: I think I found the pertinent duplicate (it wasn't easy, but I was sure that it existed and tried some searches).—BTW, the relevant term is *have-perfect* distinguishing a perfect formed with *to have* from other types of perfect formation.

Comment: @SirCornflakes that is highly relevant, although it seems that the answers focus on the particular example of "to have," whereas I'm interested in the phenomenon more generally. My question would definitely be better if I had two examples rather than one though...

Comment: I'm looking for something like the term "false cognate" (in the event that this is indeed a coincidence), but with reference to the fact that multiple senses of a word are (coincidentally?) the same across languages

Comment: If the Chinese usage were modelled after the English language, it would be a [calque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque). So perhaps one can call it a *false calque* but this is certainly not an established term.

Comment: I don't know precisely what the phenomenon is sposta be, but perhaps another example is the fact the both English and the Romance languages use _go_ + some kind of non-finite clause to indicate the future: _I'm gonna go, Vamos a ver, On va voir,_ etc. Probly the Romance constructions came from Late Latin, but English didn't.

Comment: I’m not convinced ‘coincidence’ is the best description of this particular overlap. It’s neither universal nor mandatory in any way, but making a connection between possessing an object and seeing the completed state of an action as something you can ‘possess’ is quite a likely thing to do. In broader terms, the phenomenon shows up more commonly than coincidence would dictate. It’s very obvious in much of Europe (all Germanic, Romance and some Celtic languages), but it also appears in Chinese (as you note), Japanese, Inuit languages (more obscure), and probably others.

Comment: Principled polysemy in cognitive linguistics? These phenomena are also often described as Lakoffian metaphors but that doesn’t make it much easier to search for them.

Comment: [Cross-linguistic colexification](https://clics.clld.org/)?

Comment: @alephalpha That looks like it might be it! To make sure I'm understanding here, the concepts of "possessing" and already having done something have colexified into "have" in English and "有" in Chinese?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm especially interested in cases where one of the senses is more of a grammatical/function word than a content word.

Recent studies of this phenomenon in Chinese use the term “coverb”:

- Kwan (2011) The grammar and processing of Chinese coverb constructions. http://dx.doi.org/10.5353/th_b4581596
- Amberber, Baker & Harvey (2007) Complex predication and the coverb construction. http://dx.doi.org/10.1075/cll.30.22amb

This phenomenon is highly prevalent in the Indo-Aryan languages, none of which have a verb “to have” as far as I know, but in which the andative and venitive verbs (verbs of coming and going) as well as the verbs of giving and taking fulfill grammatical roles. (To a more limited extent English verbs in these categories are also used like this, as in “go running,” or “take care.”) The term coverb has been extended to Indo-Aryan in some studies such as:

- Nazir (2014) Light verb constructions in Potwari. https://research.manchester.ac.uk/files/54567249/FULL_TEXT.PDF

Nespital’s *Dictionary of Hindi Verbs* is a monumental work on such verbs in Hindi which has not been replicated in scope as far as I know. He uses the terms Verbal Expression (VE) for “compounds” involving coverbs, and “second-member verbs” for coverbs which is a bit language specific as the order is not what is significant about them. His work is in turn inspired by analyses of verbs in Slavic languages. Chatterji & Friedrich’s *Aspect and Meaning in Slavic and Indic* offers a comparative overview of verbal constructions in the two subfamilies.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Nardog It does, but is there a problem with this answer? I was taking into consideration the fact that this question was labeled as a reference request. There is more than one way to answer this question, and some notable ones are addressed in these sources.

Comment: When I search for "coverb" I find definitions similar to: "Coverbs (CV) are transitive verbs which do not stand alone but precede and are secondary to the main verb of the sentence." This doesn't sound like it's the right concept.

Comment: @DavisYoshida Yeah I don't think that's a helpful definition. In Urdu grammar there is a term "imdadi fael" which is defined like this and it doesn't really match usage at all. The way coverbs are described in some of the papers above, and by Miriam Butt in her work on complex predicates is more fitting https://ling.sprachwiss.uni-konstanz.de/pages/home/butt/main/papers/cp-volume.pdf